# Inundated with LLC traffic

Tags: networking, router

A router (Netgear DG834GV) of mine is sending an endless stream of LLC traffic to a laptop on the network. The packets are DSAP variations on

```
3346.321206000  LLC Netgear_38:ce:5c    Apple_70:19:99  82  U, func=SIM; DSAP 0x94 Individual, SSAP ISO Network Layer (unofficial?) Command

3350.589044000  LLC Netgear_38:ce:5c    Apple_70:19:99  82  S, func=RNR, N(R)=16; DSAP 0x94 Group, SSAP ISO Network Layer (unofficial?) Response
```

and come in blocks of up-to 30 commands and 30 responses.

I've never encountered anything like this before, so don't have any idea how to determine whether the packets are innocuous. Where should I begin?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly the sniffer decoding the packets incorrectly.

In some cases if you capture on a wireless interface and either the sniffer or the wireless interface wasn't configured right, the wireless interface will pass along raw 802.11-style packets, or still-encrypted packets, when the sniffer was expecting either Ethernet/802.3 style packets or decrypted packets. 802.11 interfaces usually decrypt the packets in hardware and turn them into Ethernet-II/802.3 style frames before sending them up to the kernel's protocol stack. When a sniffer tries to interpret an encrypted 802.11 packet as if it was a cleartext 802.3 frame, it often comes out looking like some random LLC frame.

If you post the raw bytes of a packet or two I can hand-decode it and tell you if it's an encryption mismatch or if it's an 802.11 vs. 802.3 mismatch.

Comment: Appreciate the response; [here](http://pastebin.com/XAXy58Ha) are the packets above.

Comment: After looking at them, my best guess is that they're being converted from 802.11 to 802.3 format without being decrypted, but I'm not 100% sure of that. One way to check would be to temporarily disable encryption on your Netgear router and see if the mysterious LLC frames go away.